# Shortest way to write the program in Python

Tags: python

I want to know the shortest way to write the following

```
 res=[]
 for x in xrange(1,4):
     if x in [1,3]:
            res.append(1)
     else:
           res.append(0)
```

My actual problem is to turn an input like [4,6] into [0,0,0,1,0,1] where I use xrange(1,7) for instance

Comment: Try here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for general code review

Comment: Maybe even http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The example is rather tiny and the general intend not clear. The shortest way would be ```res=[1,0,1]```, which is probably not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: My actual problem is to turn an input like [4,6] into [0,0,0,1,0,1] where I use xrange(1,7) for instance

Comment: What does that mean `turn an input like [4,6] into [0,0,0,1,0,1] where I use xrange(1,7)`?

Comment: it means if I have an array [5,6] I want something like [0,0,0,0,1,1] or if I have [1,3,5] I want [1,0,1,0,1]

Comment: Is the request: "Please give me a 1-based array of 0s and 1s where the input is the index of 1s"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
res = [int(x in (1, 3)) for x in xrange(1, 4)]
```

which makes use of the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Shorter still of course is:

```
res = [1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I didnt that Bool is a subclass of int

Answer (score 2):

As short as it gets.

```
res = [1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be [1, 0, 1]?

Comment: Yes, I tested that after writing the answer. You're both right.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```py
print [int(x in [4, 6]) for x in range(1, 7)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it, with doctests built in:

```
def bit_array(series, matches):
    """
    >>> bit_array(range(1, 7), (4, 6))
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    >>> bit_array(range(1, 4), (1, 3))
    [1, 0, 1]
    """
    return [int(x in set(matches)) for x in series]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from doctest import testmod
    testmod()
```

I don't think this is the shortest because it is a function with parameters and has unit testing infrastructure, but I think it is clearest in representing its purpose. And you can always inline the function and throw away the tests once you are convinced it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way:

```
>>> [0 if i % 2 == 0 else 1 for i in range(1, 4)]
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In that particular case:

```
>>> map(int, '101')
[1, 0, 1]
```

Based on your comment:

```
>>> map(lambda e: int(e in [4,6]), xrange(1,7))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: No, because the output should be `[1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: Martijn you are correct. My actual problem is to turn an input like [4,6] into [0,0,0,1,0,1] where I use xrange(1,7)